# jquery how to select all the class elements start with "text-"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got some classes

```
.text-1
.text-2
.text-3
```

I want to select them all, how to do that?
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Try this. For more details refer [`jquery selectors`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$('*[class^="text"]')
```

Comment: The class attribute takes a space separated list of classes; this will fail on `class="foo text-1 bar"`

Comment: Then we can use $('*[class*="text"]'). this will search text as substring in class attribute. Ref: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Comment: @Chinmayee That will erroneously match something like `sometext`

Comment: @chinmayee , is he expecting all classes in that pattern or he just wants to know how to bind multiple classes together to a event.

Comment: sorry , his question was like that ...my mistake

Comment: Looks like jQuery could do with a regex attribute selector :) `$('[class~="text-\d+"]')` (yes, I know the `~=` attribute selector is already taken but it seemed like the most logical choice)

Comment: I guess then he has to use combination of both. $('*[class^="post"],*[class~="post"]')

Comment: @Phil it seems that solution you have provided is not working. Which version of jquery it requires? Check and correct if required http://jsfiddle.net/pSXVr/

Comment: @Chinmayee Sorry, it's a fictional example. I was saying it would be nice if there were a regex attribute selector. The `~=` selector is the "contains word attribute selector" (http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/) however it won't work here either

Comment: @Phil my mistake. I thought this is a feature that jquery has and I'm not aware of it. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 14):

Here's an attempt at a solution that's both accurate and not too slow:

```
var elts = $('*[class*="text-"]')
  .filter(function () {
    return this.className.match(/(?:^|\s)text-/);
  });
```

Which works by using the (hopefully) fast Sizzle code to find elements that have "text-" anywhere in their `class` attribute, and then calls a function on each of those to filter them down to the ones that actually have "text-" at the beginning of a class name.

Comment: +1 Correct answer. Also, it's faster than the solution I had, which used jQuery to get the class names. Good work.

Answer (score 4):

You don't necessarily need to specify asterisk `*`, you can do this too:

```
$('[class^="text-"]')
```

Notice the addition of `-` after `text` something you are looking for.

Check out the [jQuery starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with just two selectors in one function call:

`$('[class^="text-"], [class*=" text-"]')`

This will check if the class attribute starts with `text-` or if there is any part of the class string that has a space followed by `text-`. This solves any issues you might have with the

```js
$('[class^="text-"], [class*=" text-"]')
    .css('background-color', '#00FF00'); // add background color for demo
```

```css
/* just for demo */
div:after {
  content: "class: " attr(class);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="text-1 test"></div>
<div class="text some-text-1"></div>
<div class="nope text-long-class-name"></div>
<div class="some-text-1"></div>
<div class="even get text-n-here"></div>
```

You could pull this out into a function that selects all elements with a class that matches a given prefix, as well:

```
function selectElementsWithClassPrefix(prefix) {
    return $('[class^="' + prefix + '"], [class*=" ' + prefix + '"]');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that deals with the issue of multiple classes, in cases like `<div class="foo bar barfood">`:

```
function classStartsWith(str) {
  return $('div').map( function(i,e) {
    var classes = e.className.split(' ');
    for (var i=0, j=classes.length; i < j; i++) {
      if (classes[i].substr(0, str.length) == str) return e;
    }
  }).get();
}
```

The function returns an array of matching DOM elements. You can use it thus:

```
$( classStartsWith('text-') ).doSomething();
```

Here's an example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/Ms6ey/3/

Of course this assumes the selector `'div'`. The question seems to be asking about any element at all. It's easy enough to make the function take a selector as another argument, and use that in place of the hardcoded one in the example.

Answer (score -5):

```
$('#qvDetails,#qvAdd,.qvFramedActive,#qvMoreSizes').live('mouseover',function(){

        $(this).addClass('qvHover');                                                                            

    });
```

example from one of my projects.you can mention both divs and classes together like above

you can provide as coma separated class or divs in the same...

Comment: I gave the above example if you want to give multple classes or ids together when there is no pattern

Comment: whats wrong with above code , he didn't mention that he wants a pattern right