# jQuery selector is different for each page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have built a script that triggers a click event on click of another element. For example, user may click element A and the script triggers a click on element B.

My issue is, that the selectors I use are specific for only one page as they contain a unique ID at the end of them, for example, on one page I may have selector-123 and on another page it may be selector-456.

Here is the actual selector

```
$('#accordion-section-sidebar-widgets-obox-layers-builder-4 > h3:nth-child(1)').trigger('click');
```

the issue is that `#accordion-section-sidebar-widgets-obox-layers-builder-4` will not alway end in 4, but could end in any number.

Is there a way to use variables as my selector, something like `#accordion-section-sidebar-widgets-obox-layers-builder-*`

Comment: you could try something like explained here https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: Are you looking for a selector that will match the beginning of the ID or do you know the numeric ID for the page and you want to build the selector using that id?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161869/jquery-how-to-select-all-the-class-elements-start-with-text

Comment: @rdubya yes something that will match the start - only the number at the end changes so something like #accordion-section-sidebar-widgets-obox-layers-builder-* > h3:nth-child(1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is your html

```
<div id="accordion-section-sidebar-widgets-obox-layers-builder-4">
   hallo
</div>
<div id="accordion-section-sidebar-widgets-obox-layers-builder-6">
  bye
</div>
```

Using this

```
$('div[id^='accordion-section-sidebar-widgets-obox-layers-builder']').innerHml()
```

Will return

- hallo
- bye

Link to [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7nLzy6g6/1/)

I have left out the last part of the selector. This should get you started though.

Comment: Just read through the page you posted on my comments - that's exactly what I need - thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexp

```
​$("[id^=accordion-section-sidebar-widgets-obox-layers-builder-][id$= > h3:nth-child(1)]")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery's attribute contains prefix selector on id.

[Docs](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use contains selector http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_contain.asp