# How to select a class name knowing only a part of name in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

In Javascript with `editor.selection.getContent()` function i get the image selected in the wp editor:

```
<img class="alignnone wp-image-xxx size-large" src="http://....." alt="" />
```

i need to select the class `wp-image-xxx` and replace it with a class that include a new id (xxx).

With classList i can get all classes:

```
var imgselected = editor.selection.getNode();
var classes = imgselected.classList;
```

But how can i select in javascript the class `wp-image-xxx` without knowing the `xxx` value so to be able after to replace it?

Comment: filter them manually with `substring`

Comment: you can get the full class name as said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161869/jquery-how-to-select-all-the-class-elements-start-with-text), then you can use `split('-')` and the last array value will be your ID.

Comment: How can apply jquery selectors to the editor.selection.getContent()?

Comment: You can use the regexp jquery selector 
`$(":regex(class, .*wp-image-.*)")`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the most basic way that is applicable in your case:

```
//Replaces the first class that matches the name given as its "start" of string with a new class name;
function replaceClass(element, searchClassName, replacementClassName) {
  element.classList.remove(findClassName(document.getElementById('foo'), searchClassName));
  element.classList.add(replacementClassName)

  //used to find a className
  function findClassName(element, searchPhrase) {
    var classNameFound = "";
    element.classList.forEach(function(className) {
      if (className.substring(0, searchPhrase.length) === searchPhrase) {
        //Element found
        if (!classNameFound)
          classNameFound = className;
      }
    });
    return classNameFound;
  }
}
```

just run it with something like:

```
replaceClass(document.getElementById('foo'), 'wp-image', 'newClassName');
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I can't `getElementById` because img doesn't have an ID. I get image output with editor.selection.getContent() function:
`<img class="alignnone wp-image-xxx size-large" src="http://....." alt="" />`

Comment: you need to get the element, however way you can. Can use `getElementsByTagName('IMG')[0]` providing the image is the only and first `img` element in the parent div and that you run this on the parent if you have that ID, or select it in any other way.

Comment: You need to further explore what editor.selection offers, "getContent()" is not what you need.