# find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href') returns NoSuchElementException

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the target website for product_links. The program should open the required URL in the browser and scrape all the links with a particular class name. But for some reason, I am getting a `NoSuchElementException` for this piece of code

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("styles__StyledTitleLink-mkgs8k-5")

for link in links:
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(15)
    product_links.append(link.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href'))
```

I tried printing out the text in each link with `link.text` in the for loop. The code is actually selecting the required elements. But for some reason is not able to extract the href URL from each link. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

This is the entire error message

> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate
> element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"a"}   (Session info:
> chrome=83.0.4103.106)

Comment: can you show the example of html that represents your link

Answer (score 2):

Error seems there is no css element with 'a' so you need to try with other locators to identify elements. try with xpath=//a[contains(text(),'**text of that element**')]

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a class name generated by a builder, check the random string at the end of the class name, these classes won't be found in every web.

if you want to scrape them, find a different generic class or find all classes with a subset string "StyledTitleLink"

Here's [how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4161869/2382586) with JQuery

You should try and find a different solution to your problem

Comment: Hi. can you point me to some link on how to achieve this? Or can you provide a solution?

Comment: Yes, I've added a link to a different SO question where they answer exactly that.